# JRuby threading performance

Tags: multithreading, jruby, gil

I have written a script to test the multi-threading performance of JRuby. This script is run on a 4 core machine and other machines, and I consistently get disappointing results. Here is the script and the result. Can somebody see if there is something wrong with the script or explain why this is happening? I thought that with less (or no) reliance on Global Interpreter Lock, the multi-threading performance should be better than this.

```
class TestThread
    def calc(times)
        sum = 0;
        0.upto(times) do
            sum = (sum + 19327437) % 234978
        end
        sum
    end

    def single(times)
        time1 = Time.now
        sum = calc(times)
        time2 = Time.now
    end
end

class ThreadInvoker
    def ThreadInvoker.run(times, num_threads)
        objs = []
        threads = []

        time1 = Time.now
        num_threads.times do |n|
            obj = TestThread.new
            objs << obj
            threads << Thread.new do
                obj.single(times)
            end
        end
        threads.map(&:join)
        time2 = Time.now
        puts "#{num_threads} threads. Time elapsed #{(time2 - time1)*1000} milliseconds."
    end
end

# test = TestThread.new
ThreadInvoker.run(30000000, 1)
ThreadInvoker.run(30000000, 3)
ThreadInvoker.run(30000000, 1)
ThreadInvoker.run(30000000, 3)
ThreadInvoker.run(30000000, 1)
ThreadInvoker.run(30000000, 3)
```

Here is the result, single threaded interleaved with multi-threaded. Note that multi-threaded performance is consistently double the time it takes a single thread:

```
1 threads. Time elapsed 3292.0 milliseconds.
3 threads. Time elapsed 6880.0 milliseconds.
1 threads. Time elapsed 2995.0 milliseconds.
3 threads. Time elapsed 7270.0 milliseconds.
1 threads. Time elapsed 3120.0 milliseconds.
3 threads. Time elapsed 7613.0 milliseconds.
```

*modified to take `puts` out of the thread

Comment: Tested using jruby 1.7.4 and 1.7.11, using 64 bit Java. Both yield similar results.

Comment: there are several things wrong - code is incomplete, you do not allow for warmup but most importantly your task does no way seem implemented in a way that it would benefit multiple threads. in fact the numbers are good to see how JRuby/Java warms up since 3 threads doing the same task (3 times) does take < 1 thread x 3

Comment: I think I did allow it to warm up. The code ran 6 times, and total of 30 seconds. JIT should have warmed up by then. I interleaved the executions to avoid JIT differences too.

Comment: I am performing mutually exclusive actions in 3 separate threads. With four processors, I would expect 3 threads to take about the same total amount of time as 1 thread.

Comment: For example, similar code under clojure, 1 thread took 2081 ms while 3 threads took 2451 ms